# Redis and Laravel - Database [redis] not configured

Tags: php, laravel

Well, it's been a long couple of days but I have almost configured my Laravel app on pagodabox. i am running into a problem though. I just pushed my code, and the home page loads, but when I try to register a new user, or migrate the database using `php artisan migrate` I get the following error;

> Database [redis] not configured.

I am using Pagodabox. It takes a couple of days to get the hang of their configuration, but I have figured it out. What do I have to do to configure Redis? I checked [the documentaton](https://pagodabox.io/docs/redis) and I have been able to get Laravel to connect to the server no problem, since my home page loads. Am I missing a step? I googled around a bit and didn't find an answer. How do I configure my Redis database?

edit:

```
   <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | PDO Fetch Style
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
    | stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
    | array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
    |
    */

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'redis'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'CSToss'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
        ],




    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '192.168.0.3'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

and .env:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:oHPYI6XIKowuqfhZaLhWayKSc5bw1XlnvFKIwWZAieI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=redis
DB_HOST=http://192.168.0.3
DB_PORT=6379
DB_DATABASE=cryptoflipdb
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=192.168.0.3
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

edit: Here is my connections array from config/database.php. There is no redis array. I am looking up what to put in the connections array now

```
 'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'CSToss'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
        ],
```

Comment: make sure you have configured redis as your `.env` and in your `config/database.php` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redis)

Comment: Please post the contents of your config/database.php and your .env file

Comment: Is your redis server running?

Comment: Not sure, my host isn't letting me SSH into my database server...

Comment: can you post your connections array in config/database.php. I suspect that there is no redis defined in this array

Comment: Your DB Connections file should also have a section relating to Redis. Like: ```'redis' => [

        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', false),

        'default' => [
            'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DATABASE', 0),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        ],

    ],```

Comment: that did it. thanks.

Comment: Where is the f*** redis password?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. In our case culprit was in `config/sessions.php`:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => 'mysql',
```

This only works if you're using the database session driver. If you want to use redis, you have to change it to the proper connection name for redis. In our case, this is `default`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

whoever has that error and no luck fixing it:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
```

i had this error while trying to use another database for my tests (`.env.testing`)
hope it fix your problem as well.

Comment: Why did this fix the error?